# Finitely graded ring and zero divisors

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings

Let $R= \bigoplus_{i=0}^{d} R_i$
be a finitely graded ring such that $R_0$ is a field and $R_d \cong R_0$. I'm trying to understand how zero divisors work in such a ring; when is it true that for $r \in R$ and $s \in R$ we have $rs=0$? For example, is it true that $rs=0$ if and only if $\text{deg}(r)+\text{deg}(s) > d$?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can cook up an example where all products of elements of positive degree vanish.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you help me out with such an example? Also are there any criteria which would make the statement in the question true?

Comment: Take $k[X,Y]/(X^2,XY,Y^2)$ and assign $X$ grade 2 and $Y$ grade 4.